# Error : TransformException:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilderHoneycomb.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

I got have a error in gradle build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilderHoneycomb.class

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuvJT.png)

in my app dependencies:
[dependencies in gradle build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLMVW.png)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
})
//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'
//compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')}
```

please help me..

Comment: Do not use jars. Use gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `compile files (libs/appcompat-v4)` dependency from your build.gradle file, since it is a duplicate dependency.

Comment: i use compile files ('libs/android-support-v4.jar')